# How to solve the display_timer_callback error in Xcode when making a network call?

Tags: swift, xcode, api, callback, runtime-error

I'm getting an error in the Xcode console that I've never had before. 
This happens when I scroll my tableView (when I get to the bottom of the list it calls the `loadMoreRecipe()` method which makes a network call to get more results the error doesn't appear on each call but rather randomly), yet I didn't change any important code.

Here is the error in question:

> 2019-07-07 22:10:57.586543+0200
>   P10_Reciplease[6188:2107230][WindowServer] display_timer_callback:
>   unexpected state (now:50d5cc1f65a < expected:50d5cc80a6c)

```
func loadMoreRecipes(indexPath: Int) {
    print(indexPath + 1)
    guard indexPath == hits.count - 1 else { return }
    guard let apiHelper = apiHelper else { return }
    print("le nombre total de recette est : ", hits.count)
    apiHelper.from = hits.count + 1
    apiHelper.to = apiHelper.from + 10

    startAnimatingActivityIndicator()

    apiHelper.getRecipe(userIngredients: userIngredients, callback: { [weak self] (apiResult, statusCode)  in
        guard let apiResult = apiResult else {

            apiHelper.from = self?.hits.count ?? 0
            apiHelper.to = apiHelper.from + 10

            self?.switchStatusCode(statusCode: statusCode)

            if let apiHelper = self?.apiHelper {
                apiHelper.from = self?.hits.count ?? 0
                apiHelper.to = apiHelper.from + 10
            }
            self?.stopAnimatingActivityIndicator()
            return
        }
        guard !apiResult.hits.isEmpty else {
            self?.parent?.presentAlert(titleAlert: .sorry, messageAlert: .noOtherRecipesFound, actionTitle: .ok, statusCode: nil, completion: nil)
            if let apiHelper = self?.apiHelper {
                apiHelper.from = self?.hits.count ?? 0
                apiHelper.to = apiHelper.from + 10
            }
            self?.stopAnimatingActivityIndicator()
            return
        }
        self?.stopAnimatingActivityIndicator()
        self?.hits.append(contentsOf: apiResult.hits)
        self?.tableView.reloadData()
    })
}
```